What is the best way to grant user on sql
I am trying to learn the best methods to grant user privileges on database
CREATE USER IF NOT EXIST `'silas'@localhost'` IDENTIFIED BY '1234' 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'silas'@'localhost';

or
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `my_db.*` TO `'silas'@'localhost'`;

I am just trying to find the best way to do this.

I am just trying to find the best way to do this. There is no "the best way". You must grant only needed privileges on only needed objects. 1st code grants all privileges on all databases whereas 2nd one grants all privileges on all objects within one database only.

In current versions of MySQL, you must use CREATE USER before you can GRANT privileges to that user. In old versions of MySQL, GRANT to a non-existent user would implicitly create that user, but this feature turns out to be a security risk, because you could inadvertently create a user with no password. So they don't allow implicit create of user by default in modern versions.

so lets break it down and this might help you understand when to use which, there is no There is no "the best way".

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'silas'@'localhost';


This above gives silas complete control over every database on the server.

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `my_db`.* TO 'silas'@'localhost';


This above limits silas' full control to just the my_db database, while other databases remain protected.

GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON `my_db`.* TO 'silas'@'localhost';


This above grants silas the ability to only read (SELECT) and insert (INSERT) data, without allowing them to delete or modify database structures.

I would strongly recommend to grant specific privileges instead of ALL unless it's absolutely necessary like below statement which only granting select, insert and update privilege on my_db database.
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON my_db.* TO 'silas'@'localhost';

I would also recommend to use specific database name if not it's necessary.
instead of .* my_db.* is safer option when you just want to give privilege on my_db database
And please use FLUSH PRIVILEGES; after granting the privilege to ensure immediate effect.

@Akina thanks for your feed back. I have revised my answer.

It is not necessary to use FLUSH PRIVILEGES after GRANT or REVOKE. It does no harm, but it's redundant. Use FLUSH PRIVILEGES is needed only if you manipulate the privilege tables directly with INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

@silas if this answer helped you please accept it as answer by clicking the greet button to mark this question as answered.
